# Task Manager shows Hard drive at 100%

Tags: windows

My hard drive is at 100% in Task Manager.
I disabled Windows Search and Superfetch and hard drive is still at 100%.
I am using Windows 10.
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Update: Task Manager won't show what process is clogging up hard drive at 100%.
Task Manager won't show any processes that use up a lot of percentage of hard drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue on my **WINDOWS 10** system and I tried a lot of things like turning off the search indexing feature of windows but nothing worked using all that. Here is what worked for me. I opened the task manager and found that there was a task with **Microsoft Compatibility Telemetry (CompatTelRunner.exe)**. It is a Windows process that is designed to collect and send usage and performance data to Microsoft. The executable file collects and regularly sends usage and performance information to Microsoft in order to analyze the user experience and improve it. The described file also helps Microsoft to identify compatibility issues and ensure compatibility when installing the latest Windows OS version. However, Microsoft Compatibility Telemetry eats CPU by scanning computer files and check their compatibility with Windows 10 in case an update is initiated.

**I simply clicked on End Task for  Microsoft Compatibility Telemetry and my disk usage went from 98% to 15% within few seconds. I hope it helps others experiencing the same issue as well.**

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you see the processes tab and see if any process that might be using maximum read/writes in your hard drive.

Disable Indexing service that sometimes use more resources. Disable any startup process that might be using your system resources.

Windows + R -> Run Menu -> Type: msconfig and see any startup process that you can disable. Disable any program that seems suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

You can try some other repair methods like:

- Perform a diskcheck
- Reset Virtual Memory
- Disable Antivirus Software temporarily
- Change the settings in Google & Skype
- Fix your StorAHCI.sys driver
- Update your device drivers

[Win10 100% disk usage](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/fix-100-disk-usage-in-task-manager-improve-pc-performance-on-windows-10/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with windows 10 on Laptop.
I set the windows update service from automatic to manual.
Now i am always under 5%.

- Click on administrative tools in control panel
- Then click on Services
- set windows update to manual.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem for months. Desactivated SrTasks.exe and it started working.
However this task is clearly something important, so I think it's not recommanded to stop it.