# 100% disk. Unknown utilization

Tags: windows-10, disk

Is the 100% disk, capacity? THe C drive is half empty...

Even in the usage, its sorted by usage, and it does not make sense. Did something happen to my disk? I never saw it in 100%.

[image]

[image]

Comment: use a SSD and not a HDD

Comment: Maybe one of my answers on the same question here can help: [stackoverflow.com/a/68766676/6565832](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68766676/6565832)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same performance issue and determined the cause to be Google Chrome Privacy and Security settings.

Try:

1. Open Google Chrome settings.
2. Navigate to the Privacy and Security menu.
3. Turn off "Use a prediction service to load pages more quickly."

After I changed the above Google Chrome setting my disk usage dropped from 100%  to 3%.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes can be usefull cleaning the fan because Windows can notify 100% Disk usage but it's not a disk's problem. The high temperature of hardware system can be observed as a disk exception by the operating system but in fact it's not. So, clean the fan everything will fine.