# How to solve "Windows 10 Disk Usage 100 percent in Task manager"?

Tags: windows

I felt this several times before and also now the situation is same as before - always 90~100%.
I checked the almost Youtube video lectures related with this.
I did as following but all didn't help me.
How can I solve it?

```
1. Start/Run/services.msc -> Disable and stop the "Windows Search" service.
2. Start/Task Scheduler/Task Scheduler Library/Microsoft/Windows/Dfrag -> in the right side, click the "End".
3. Update my drives.
4. superfetch service stop. (in the Youtube video recommended, but there is no such service in my computer,so I was unable to do it)
5. My Computer -> mouse right click -> properties -> Advanced system settings -> Performance -> Settings -> Advanced -> Virtual memory Change setting(as Youtube video)
6. Skype.exe -> properties -> give write access.
7. Services -> Disabled the "Windows Update" service.
```

But none of this helped me. Any help will be appreciated.
How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: When you are not using heavy software, it is always 100%?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes. always 100%

Comment: Maybe one of my answers on the same question here can help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68766676/6565832

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried with this, And maybe it might be different for your configuration.
I wish this will help you.

Mind: *Superfetch* was changed to *Sysmain* in new Windows.

- Start -> run -> enter: regedit
- Go to: `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\PrefetchParameters`

- EnablePrefetcher -> modify: enter 2 (default: 3)
- EnableSuperfetch -> modify: enter 1 (default: 3)

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my ROG laptop. Disk usage at almost 100% even when idling.

It turned out that the original SSD of the laptop had been swapped for HDD (it was not purchased new). While this is not by itself a problem, as I don't mind the difference in speed that much, the laptop for some reason found it to be. I'm guessing some drivers for the laptop are configured to expect SSD performance.

In any case, my problem was solved by reinstalling the OS on an SSD.